# How does iBooks implements its highlight text feature?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I would like to do something similar for an HTML document or PDF. How should I go about implementing this feature?

Answer (score 0):

For an html document, I'd look into doing some simple javascript/css coding.

Comment: How would you write something like that in javascript? iBooks uses epub which is based in html right?

Comment: Yes epub is based on XHTML 1.1
As far as coding, checkout:
http://eriwen.com/javascript/highlight-search-results-with-js/
for some basics.  (I haven't tried the code in that page but at a quick glance it looks like it will work)

Answer (score 0):

Try FastPDFKit, you can perform search and results will be highlighted.

http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit

Answer (score 0):

iBook uses JavaScript to get the selected text and it uses **Images** to show highlighted portion.

Comment: HOW COULD YOU SAY THIS. HAVE YOU IMPLEMENT HIGHLIGHT AND SAVE FUNCTIONALITY ON WEBVIEW

Comment: @Soniya I have experience working with this kind of functionality. If you want to be sure just extract iBook IPA file so you will come to know the file structure inside.